# NLP - Queries using semantic wildcards in full text searching, maybe with Lucene?

Tags: algorithm, lucene, full-text-search, nlp, wildcard

Let's say I have a big corpus (for example in english or an arbitrary language), and I want to perform some semantic search on it.
For example I have the query:

*"Be careful: [art] armada of [sg] is coming to [do sg]!"*

And the corpus contains the following sentence:

*"Be careful: an armada of alien ships is coming to destroy our planet!"*

It can be seen that my query string could contain "semantic placeholders", such as:

- [art] - some placeholder for articles (for example a / an in English)
- [sg], [do sg] - some placeholders for NPs and VPs (subjects and predicates)

I would like to develop a library which would be capable to handle these queries efficiently.
I suspect that some kind of POS-tagging would be necessary for parsing the text, but because I don't want to fully reimplement an already existing full-text search engine to make it work, I'm considering that how could I integrate this behaviour into a search engine like Lucene?

I know there are SpanQueries which could behave similarly in some cases, but as I can see, Lucene doesn't do any semantic stuff with stored texts.

It is possible to implement a behavior like this? Or do I have to write an own search engine?

Comment: Consider asking this question on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or on [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is a theoretical description of how it can be done using suffix arrays (very time efficient, esp. when all is done in memory, but consumes a lot of space): http://www.aclweb.org/anthology-new/R/R11/R11-1067.pdf The open-source library version of this isn't quite ready yet, but perhaps you find the description useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With Lucene, you could add additional tokens to a single item in a TokenStream, but I wouldn't know how to deal with tags that span more than one word.